# Why is "kill" different from a terminal and from system()?

Tags: linux, bash, perl, ssh

When I run the below script, which will execute `sleep 123` on a remote host, and then kill the local ssh process, which will exit `sleep 123` on the remote host. This is the expected behaviour.

However if I remove `system("kill $p")` and execute the `kill` command from a terminal with the process ID, when the local ssh is killed, but the remote `sleep 123` survives. Not expected.

```
# /usr/gnu/bin/kill 961
Killed by signal 15.
```

**Question**

Why is the same `kill` command different depending on executing it from Perl's `system()` and from a terminal, and how can the remote `sleep 123` command survive when the ssh connection is killed?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl    
use strict;
use warnings;
use Parallel::ForkManager;

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(5);
my $pid = $pm->start;
my $p = $pid;
if (!$pid) {
    system("ssh 10.10.47.47 sleep 123");
    $pm->finish;
}

$p = qx(/usr/bin/pgrep -P $p);
print "ssh pid is $p\n";

system("/usr/gnu/bin/kill $p");
```

Comment: `kill` is a builtin command in bash. I haven't checked, but its behavior might differ from that of `/usr/bin/kill` or `/usr/gnu/bin/kill`.

Comment: You've got a nasty race condition in your code. If the `ssh` process dies between the time you call `pgrep` and `kill` and a new process gets the same PID, you could be sending `kill` to the wrong process.

Comment: I believe you are mistaken.

Comment: Interactively, are you running `/usr/gnu/bin/kill` with the pid from the `ssh pid is ..` message? Does the script exit in the mean time?

Comment: @thatotherguy The Perl script is still running as the script forked the ssh process, and so returns the terminal. Yes, that is the pid I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even to a local host, `ssh` will take tens of milliseconds to connect and execute the command.

When killed by the script, `ssh` is dies within a few milliseconds of starting, so it never gets a chance to execute the command on the remote host.

When killed by a human, `ssh` has multiple seconds to connect and execute.

In other words, the `sleep` doesn't die in the first case -- it never starts.

You can confirm this by making your script wait a second before killing ssh.

Comment: Now I inserted a `sleep 5` just before the kill, and the script now  outputs `Killed by signal 15.`, but now the remote `sleep 123` isn't killed either. So you are right =) But why does the remote `sleep 123` survive?

Comment: `sleep` doesn't care if the terminal disappears from under it, and the ssh shell isn't interactive so it won't SIGHUP the process when it's disconnected.